# Is it possible to set background of the whole app in React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

When i change the views back and forth previous view  goes smaller and white frame appears. I think this is just a background of the app or something. Is it possible to change the color in React Native or probably in X-Code?

Comment: if you're using Navigator then pass custom style to style attribute with backgroundColor :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to AppDelegate.m

```
  self.window.rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.05 green:0.39 blue:0.70 alpha:1.0];
```

This will change it to blue.